# How to define multiple "yield :something" in the Phoenix layout?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a layout with this:

```
# main_layout.html.eex
<html>
    <head>

    <............>
    </head>


    <div class="main_content">
      <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) %>
    </div>

    <footer ......>
```

And many child pages. However, in some(!) child pages I want to render html outside of

```
    <div class="main_content">
      <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) %>
    </div>
```

That is, I want to **append** some additional html into `"<footer ...>"` and above the `"<div class="main_content">"` tag

The rest of the pages should continue rendering the normal way: without these additional htmls parts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One might render as many templates as they needed.

```rb
<div class="main_content">
  <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) %>
</div>

<footer>
  <%= render(@footer_module, @footer_template, assigns) %>
</footer>
```

The conditional rendering might be done either from the topmost template:

```rb
<footer>
  <%= if ... do %>
    <%= render(@footer_module, @footer_template, assigns) %>
  <% end %>
</footer>
```

Or from the `FooterModule` itself, rendering nothing if there is no need to.

---

In case the information you are to add to the footer differs from child to child, use [`Phoenix.View.render_existing/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3) and simply do not provide templates where they are not needed: phoenix will silently ignore this directive for non-existing templates.

Comment: What's `footer_module`? How would I render it in my child template?

Comment: `footer_module` is your module providing a functionality you want to add to the footer. It’s rendered from the main template as shown above.

Comment: @Ojrojako when mudasobwa says FooterModule he's only using that as an example of what you're trying to render into the layout. To expand on that example each template e.g. `app/lib/app_web/templates/page/index.html.eex` eventually gets converted into functions in their corresponding view e.g. `/app/lib/app_web/views/page_view.ex`. A common practice is to have a shared folder and SharedView for shared templates e.g. `<%= render AppWeb.SharedView, "_foot.html", conn: @conn %>`. Depending on where or when you need that template rendered you could use `if`, `cond`, `case`, `unless` to display it.